# Applying the counter from collection to a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, collections, counter

I have a column of strings, where each row is a list of strings. I want to count the elements of the column in its entirety and not just the rows which one gets with the value.counts() in pandas.
I want to apply the Counter() from the Collections module, but that runs only on a list. My column in the DataFrame looks like this:

```
[['FollowFriday', 'Awesome'],
 ['Covid_19', 'corona', 'Notagain'],
 ['Awesome'],
 ['FollowFriday', 'Awesome'],
 [],
 ['corona', Notagain],
....]
```

I want to get the counts, such as

```
[('FollowFriday', 2),
 ('Awesome', 3),
 ('Corona', 2),
 ('Covid19'),
 ('Notagain', 2),
 .....]
```

The basic command that I am using is:

```
from collection import Counter
Counter(df['column'])
```

OR

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(" ".join(df['column']).split()).most_common()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `value_counts` to count values, combine with `head(N)` to get the top N. You should improve the question with clear input if you don't manage

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but like I explained, value_counts() counts the rows, so I get count = 1 for each of the rows. But, I want to count the different values inside each of the rows and also across all the rows. Is there a way, I could do that with value_counts() ?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible input and output, as real DataFrame constructor, not lists. Or was it just an analogy to pandas and you want to do it with pure python?

Comment: It was an analogy. I have a Dataframe column, which as I understand is a series. And, I need to find out the count of all the text (words) in that column, where the text(words) are repeated in an unordered fashion across the rows as in my example

Comment: I got the above list by using: col_list = df['column'].values.tolist(), thinking that it will solve my problem but it just made a list of the already present lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, your comparison to pandas was only to explain your goal and you want to work with lists?

You can use:

```
l = [['FollowFriday', 'Awesome'],
     ['Covid_19', 'corona', 'Notagain'],
     ['Awesome'],
     ['FollowFriday', 'Awesome'],
     [],
     ['corona', 'Notagain'],
    ]

from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

out = Counter(chain.from_iterable(l))
```

or if you have a Series of lists, use `explode`:

```
out = Counter(df['column'].explode())
# OR
out = df['column'].explode().value_counts()
```

output:

```
Counter({'FollowFriday': 2,
         'Awesome': 3,
         'Covid_19': 1,
         'corona': 2,
         'Notagain': 2})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. out = Counter(df['column'].explode())
# OR
out = df['column'].explode().value_counts() works.

Comment: You might have a "sublist" that is a float?

Comment: How can I use .head(N) with the above code? You mentioned it in your earlier comment, but when I use it with value_counts, i.e., df['column'].explode().value_counts().head(N), it says that : name N is not defined.

Comment: well, define N: `N = 5`

Comment: I am running into another problem now. When trying to save the output of the counter, I am getting the error " 'str' object has no attribute 'keys' ". Can you please help me fix it? I tried saving it with: import csv
csv_columns = ['Counts']

csv_file = "file.csv"
try:
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
        writer.writeheader()
        for data in output:
            writer.writerow(data)
except IOError:
    print("I/O error")

Comment: It's quite difficult to follow code in comments, you should start a new question ;)

Comment: Have there been any updates to the module? I tried the code that you suggested again today, and it gave me a different answer. The only change that I had in my data is that now, I converted all the values to lowercase. df['column'].explode().value_counts() does not separate out the values anymore. Any ideas, why this might be happening?

Comment: @Abir no, but python is case sensitive. `ABC` and `abc` won't be counted as the same element ;)

Comment: I know, that is why I changed it to lowercase as there were some observations that were the same but in lowercase. So, I wanted to add after converting it all to lowercase.

Comment: Sorry, but as I said last time, debugging without data is quite difficult. You should open a new question will all the details

Comment: explode.value_counts() works like a charm! Thanks :)